# Delete from tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def distanceFromGPS(latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2):
    R = 6371
    dLat = math.radians(latitude2-latitude1)
    dLon = math.radians(longitude2-longitude1)
    a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude1)) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude2))
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = R * c
    return d  

a = [(1,1),(4,4),(1.001,1),(1,1.001),(1.0000001,1),(1,1.0000000001)]
lst=[]
for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(a, L):
      if len(subset) == len(a):
          for i in range(0,len(a)):
              for j in range(1,len(a)):
                  if distanceFromGPS(subset[i][0],subset[i][1],subset[j][0],subset[j][1]) < 1:
                      del(subset[j])
              lst.append(subset[i])
print len(set(lst))
```

I am trying to delete all the lat long pairs if the distance between them is less than 1 km, keeping only one of them e.g. in the list of tuples a, they are all latitude longitude pairs. The distance between all of them except (4,4) is less than 1 km. So I want only one of those to show up in the `print len(set(lst))`, making the code print 2. The function `distanceFromGPS` return distance between two lat long pairs in km. The code that I've written doesn't work and there ought to be a better way than using four for loops! Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touples are immutable so you can't use "del" to delete one of their items.

You can do this instead:

```
mytouple = mytouple[:indexToDelete] + mytouple[indexToDelete+1:]
```

Another way would be to use lists (which are mutable and work with "del") instead of touples. Although that can cause a small performance drop.

Also, if you are deleting from a list/touple/array, you should iterate it from end to start (which means your last for loop should change). That's because if you actually delete an item, your loop won't check the next item and jump over it.

This code should work with less loops.

```
def distanceFromGPS(latitude1,longitude1,latitude2,longitude2):
    R = 6371
    dLat = math.radians(latitude2-latitude1)
    dLon = math.radians(longitude2-longitude1)
    a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude1)) * math.cos(math.radians(latitude2))
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = R * c
    return d  

a = [(1,1),(4,4),(1.001,1),(1,1.001),(1.0000001,1),(1,1.0000000001)]

for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    for j in range(len(a)-1,i, -1):
        if distanceFromGPS(a[i][0],a[i][1],a[j][0],a[j][1]) < 1:
            a = a[:j] + a[j+1:]

print(set(a))
```

Comment: I get this error. IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Edit: I ran you code and got the same error. That's because you are still iterating over "a" while you are accessing "subset"

Comment: Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution is the following:

```
from itertools import product

a = [....]
results = set()

for pair in product(a, a):
   left, right = pair
   if distanceFromGPS(left[0], left[1], right[0], right[1]) > 1:
     results.add(left)
```

Comment: It doens't give the desired output.